# Reversal of the value of variable upon callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I achieve this? Firstly the code...

```
 function flutter() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    var $obj = $('.bird');
    $obj.animate({ top :'-=' + random + 'px' }, 20, flutter);
    } 
</script>
```

In the code above, when the callback is executed, I want to reverse the value of random. My goal is thus to move the Class bird up and down and  try to see if it create fluttering effect.

Comment: what the first call to `flutter` looks like?

Comment: Just flutter(); @Cherniv, my target is like this...firstly execute the function as flutter();, then in next execution or callback not to execute the first line of the function flutter where the random number is created but to reverse just the number that was before and use it and continue reversing each time. That means, just execute the first line of the function for the first time. Am I thinking this correctly? Is there a better way of doing it? I am new to JS so please bear with me. Also I made a small correction to the code above. Flutter does not have any arguments.

Comment: i see . i've updated my code , have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some closure like this:

```
$obj.animate({ top :'-=' + random + 'px' }, 20, function(){ 
   flutter(random*-1);
});
```

And this is the full code:

```
function flutter(offset) {
    var random = ( isNaN(offset) ) ? Math.floor(Math.random()*5) : (offset) ;
    var $obj = $('.bird');
    $obj.animate({ top :'-=' + random + 'px' }, 20, function(){ 
       flutter(random*-1);
    });
 }
```

And first call will be simple: `flutter();`

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Just about 7 years experience in client-side developing and beer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I just tweaked flutter above to make it more efficient and convenient.

```
 function flutter(distance, target) {
    // you can call flutter without argument. And no repetitive element finding is needed
    var random = distance || Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    var $obj = target || $('.bird');
    $obj.animate({ top :'-=' + random + 'px' }, 20, function(){
        flutter(-random, $obj);
    });
    }
```